# Column index out of range exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to fetch an id from a table where the name(KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME ) matches the given name.
table contains three coloumn KEY_CUSTOMER_ID,KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME ,KEY_CUSTOMER_GENDER

my query

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM " +TABLE_NAME +" where name = '"+names+"'", null);
```

its running fine...but i wanna perform it using query method of sqlite used in android

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ KEY_CUSTOMER_ID }, KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME, new String[] {    String.valueOf(names) }, null, null, null);
```

but its showing out of range exception.

Comment: `KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME` => `KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME + "=?"`

Comment: what is `KEY_CUSTOMER_ID ` ,`KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME ` and `names` ?

Comment: thanks...it worked...space problem..@Selvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_CUSTOMER_ID, KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME  }, KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: but the main problem was of space...

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ KEY_CUSTOMER_ID }, "KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME =?", new String[] { String.valueOf(names) }, null, null, null);
```

Where KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME should be column name of table

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this.

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ KEY_CUSTOMER_ID }, KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME+" = "+new String[] { String.valueOf(names) }, null, null, null, null);
```